# ClientX and ClientY Reference Error in firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I have a simple jquery program where a div should get displayed based on co-ordinates
 of the mouse on hover of comment . I have used event.clientX and event.clientY function unfortunately  these function are not working in firefox browsers (Error in firefox is "ReferenceError: event is not defined") . Works fine in Chrome and IE. Please kindly help.Thanks.

```
<div class="comment"></div>
<div class="commentBox">
 <p>welcome</p>
 </div>

$('.comment').hover(function(e){

     var x=event.clientX
 var y=event.clientY
  x=x-263;

$('.commentBox').css({"left":x+"px","top":y+"px"});


    $('.commentBox').css('visibility','visible');

    },function(e){


        $('.commentBox').css('visibility','visible');
  });
```

Comment: You have used e in function for hover and used event inside the function which is the cause of issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.comment').hover(function(e){

     var x=e.clientX;//replaced event with e
     var y=e.clientY;////replaced event with e
```

You have parameter `e` instead of `event`. So you get `ReferenceError: event is not defined`.